# Google Cloud for source code backup and document storage

Tags: google-cloud

I am using Google Drive to store critical documents and source code backups. Google Drive does not encrypt data at rest.

I just checked Google Cloud which has following options:

1. Standard
2. DRA
3. Nearline

Can I make use of Standard or DRA for document storage?

Does it encrypt data at rest?

Comment: Google Drive does not encrypt any document stored on it.  It implements a simple (relative simple) file sharing permission system.  If you have criticial senistive documents you should use something other then Google Drive.

Comment: Actually, @CharlieRB, this is about the file storage/synchronization aspect of Google Drive, _not_ the web interface. Therefore it _is_ on-topic at [su].

Comment: Actually, Drive data is now encrypted at rest. This is documented here: https://support.google.com/work/answer/6056693?hl=en under the last topic "How is data encrypted at rest within Google Apps for Work?". While this article addresses the enterprise version of Drive, I can't see Google running two different services for enterprise vs consumer Drive. Google started encrypting at rest a few years ago to meet enterprise requirements and in response to the Snowden / NSA revelations.